# It's "application on" or "application in"

Tags: grammar, writing, syntactic-analysis

Which one is correct:

> We show its application on

Or

> We show its application in

"its" refer to something (e.g. method).

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please give the phrase in context.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the question is ambiguous and a proper answer will require more context. For example,

We show [the method's] application on page 9.
We show [the method's] application in the following examples.